# Delete Sheets Based On Sheet Positions In Workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm extremely new to scripts. I'm trying to delete sheets between sheet 2 and sheet 10. I'm using `sheet()` to name the sheets so they are named their respective positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getSheets()
                .slice(1, 10)
                .forEach(i => 
                  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(i)
                )

}
```

Here is a dynamic way to delete all sheets from the 2nd to 10th sheet.

This works by getting all sheets (`.getSheets()`) and only keeping a segment of them (`.slice()`). For each of these sheets (`.forEach()`) we delete them.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Delete() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(3)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(4)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(5)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(6)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(7)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(8)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet(9)'), true);
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
};
```

WHERE sheet(?) IS NAME